# How do I create secure token authentication with Django Rest Framework/React?

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am currently creating a website using React for the frontend and Django Rest Framework for an API. I decided to use token authentication as I figured it would be an extensible option if I ever decide to create a mobile app in addition to my web application.

At the moment, I am creating one token for each new user, and I have no method of refreshing or changing the token. On login, the frontend passes the username and password to Django, which either creates or retrieves a token and sends it back to be used for future calls to the API.

This is the view I am using to do so:

```
class GetAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
    # Used to retrieve an auth token with a username and password
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
        })
```

The fact that my tokens never change doesn't seem especially secure and makes me think I have to rethink my authentication/authorization strategy. I'm really not sure where to go from here though, and I had trouble finding help online since my combination of React and DRF isn't especially popular from what I can tell. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not use JWT tokens? They are very secure due to the way they work. This might help - https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

Comment: And yes, if the token you create never changes, it kind of defeats the purpose. Specially when people can bypass authorization using the token even way say, a user might be blocked. This may just be an edge-case but still. You would manually have to do something to remove the token from your server and db rather than it expiring after a set time period.

Comment: And you don't really need to worry about how you handle things on the React part of your application, Django will be creating the token and Django will be doing the Auth check. React's only job is to retrieve the token from the Response body and storing it in a place like your browser's Local Storage, and when you do send subsequent requests you need to retrieve it and append it to your request headers.

Comment: Sounds good, I think this is what I need. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Good tutorial about Django and React: [Django+React app tutorial](https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/). In this tutorial default DRF auth token is used. The token is recreated on every login and destroyed when user log out.

Comment: I want to ask a question here. Isn't jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt  unmaintained. So, should I use it?